# JPA createNativeQuery call procedure with non standart name

Tags: jpa

I'm trying to call an Oracle procedure using Persistence API:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void removeProcess(User user, BigDecimal processId) {
    EntityManager em = emb.createEntityManager(user);
    em.createNativeQuery("{ call DOF.DF#DEL_PROCESS(?) }")
      .setParameter(1, processId)
      .executeUpdate();
    em.close();
}
```

And I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
Error Code: 17003
Call: { call DOF."DF?)" }
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
```

If i copy DF#DEL_PROCESS to DF_DEL_PROCESS all works fine. How can I escape # in the procedure name??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'#' is the default parameter marker used internal in EclipseLink.

You can change this using the query hint, "eclipselink.jdbc.parameter-delimiter"

Also, if you inline the parameter instead of using setParameter() it should also work.